# Tensorflow object detection api model to tflite

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way to convert tensorflow Api models to Tflite for example(faster-rcnn model to tflite model)

if yes would like to know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please go to https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert for general instructions to convert. If you're looking for models to start, go to https://www.tensorflow.org/hub.